# How to select mesh faces along a 3D line using python?

Tags: python, blender

I am using blender 2.72

I have a terrain that is represented by a mesh. I want to be able to select faces (edges,nodes) within this mesh that lie along a 3D line. I have not been able to find any python instruction within the Blender API that will allow me to do this.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Thank you.

M.

Comment: I think you do selection by casting a ray and testing intersection. [mathutils.geometry](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72b_release/mathutils.geometry.html) would be the place to start. [CGCookies contours addon](https://github.com/CGCookie/retopology-contours) might be an example to look at.

Comment: thanks, there is a reference to a page in the link you sent me that might have what I am looking for (#Mesh intersection script): http://airplanes3d.net/scripts-253_e.xml

Comment: '3D line' can you elaborate.  Is this a single line defined by 2 points, or is it like a path or curve.  Eg, a series of verts.